# csv loader error - WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, csv

I am using this WordPress plugin.

```
http://allaerd.org/woocommerce-csv-importer
```

And when I try to load the csv with images (they are .jpg format) I get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/*******/public_html/**********/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/include/woocommerce-csvimport-functions.php on line 218
```

So I tried different options. Like changing columns separator to | and other things. But no luck. I replaced all the | with commas , and made sure that the rest of the text doesn't have commas that would disrupt the order of columns. Still no luck I get the same error.

I tried with 2 products in csv and 2 jpg images and again I got the same error.

Help?

Comment: Can you share the code that's on/around line 218?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GiM9GcfB
It's right here.

Comment: Which line in pastebin refers to your WP line 218?

Comment: It is the line 13 $x = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, (int)$new_cat['term_id'], 'product_cat', true );